# How large, slow, and/or close would the moon need to be to block the sun for at least a few hours?

Tags: moons, day-night

Suppose everything about our world is consistent. I will tweak it from there.

Alternatively, reverse it; suppose the moon was habitable and the planet hostile. How large, etc, would that planet need to be to create a false night period?

I'll go with whichever one works.

Comment: A gas giant would do, but it'll be an extra night per month or more. You can't block the sunlight with an ordinary planet or a moon for that long, and you can't have a fast orbiting moon AND blocking sunlight for hours, either one or the other.

Comment: Do you want to block the sun for a few hours every day or is an occasional extra night every month or similar sufficient?

Comment: A few hours every couple days wouldn't be too much

Answer (score 3):

Let's make a ballpark estimate:

The sun completes an apparent roundtrip in sky in 24 hours. So it covers 360 degrees in 24 hours, or 15 degrees/hour.

Considering that the sun apparent size in the sky is about 0.5 degrees and assuming this object is standing still in the sky, it should be about 30 times larger than the apparent size of sun to obscure it for 1 hour.

How large an object appear can be simply calculated by considering that, called S its size and D its distance, $ \alpha = 2 \arctan(S/2D)$.

For a reference, something at the distance of the Moon would need to be about 105000 kilometers wide to have an angular size of 15 degrees (the Moon is 3400 km in diameter)

Comment: *"105000 kilometers wide":* That is eight times the diameters of the Earth. Earth is only 12,800 km wide.

Comment: The 24 hour day cycle is not relevant to how long an orbit takes to move the moon past the sun. It's the period of the *moon* in its orbit, which is roughly 30 days.  The *track* of the moon on the Earth during an eclipse takes some hours already. You would need to make the moon large enough such that the area of totality was larger. Oddly enough, that's back to not too far from your number.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the track of the moon's shadow on the Earth during an eclipse of the sun takes some hours.

Totality only occurs for a small area on the Earth's surface, sometimes only a few 100 km. This is because totality only occurs when the location on the Earth is sufficiently close to the moon as the shadow passes over. It's a complicated thing resulting from the orbit of the moon not being perfectly circular, the orbit of the moon not being perfectly lined up with the Earth's equator, and the surface of the Earth not being perfectly spherical. When the equatorial bulge helps out, and other things line up just perfectly, you get the longest totality.

To make totality last some hours you would need to make the moon large enough such that totality covered a larger area. Currently, the longest totality is something like 7 minutes.  So to get 3 hours you would need about 25 times as wide a moon. This is getting up to Jupiter range. Tides would be pretty horrendous, though we would still be outside the Roche limit. And this would still only produce 3 hours at the optimum.

Moving the moon *closer* might help.

The speed of an orbit is proportional to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{R}} $. That is, 4 times closer moves twice as fast. The apparent diameter is proportional to $R$. So 4 times closer appears 4 times as wide. Also, closer means you are further up the cone of the moon's shadow. So 4 times closer is effectively taking twice as long to transit the apparent width of the moon. And totality is more frequent and happens over larger areas of the surface.

Moving it farther away will make things worse. 4 times as far means 1/4 the apparent diameter at only 1/2 the speed. Meaning it takes 1/2 as long to transit its apparent diameter.

So if you had something about 12.5 times the diameter of the moon, at 1/4 it's current orbital distance, you would get totality for something in the range of up to 3 hours. Since it's orbit would be about 2 weeks, you would get a partial eclipse that often, and a total a few times per year.

And tides would be a massive hazard.

Comment: I see the tides as a non-issue - it literally just so happens that this setting I'm working on is dominated by aquatic lifeforms.

Answer (score 0):

The moon and the sun are already the same apparent size (not actual size), which is why we have eclipses. The reason for this: coincidence.

So the answer to how large and close would it have to be is the current largeness and closeness. The Sun's diameter is about 400× that of his wife, but the Sun is about 400× further away, making them seem the same size. For your question, any combination of distance and size that renders the moon as apparently big or bigger than the sun would work.

How slow would it have to be to block it for "a few hours"? The Moon has an orbital speed of 1.022 km/s and solar eclipses last a few minutes, so if it was sixty times slower (1.022 km/minute) they would last a few hours.

Comment: Sixty times slower on a circular orbit around Earth would require a semi-major axis of more than 9.2 astronomical units for this potential moon orbit,and if it were possible, would prevent any solar eclipses from happening.

Comment: That slower speed is doable with an elliptical orbit, I'm just not certain without doing the calculations if such an orbit exists with that slow a speed at apogee and that misses the planet at perigee and still fits inside Earth's hill sphere.

Comment: @novotny: [Molniya orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_orbit). Named after the Soviet [*Molniya*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molniya_(satellite)) (Lightning) series of communication satellites, first launched in 1965.

Comment: Yes, but when it's close enough to the Earth to cast a shadow it will be moving faster. Remember Kepler's law of equal areas.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks for the mention of the Molniya orbit; it's reminded me that the major issue is not the speed of the moon, but the relative speed of the moon's shadow and the observing point on the ground. I suspect you might be able to do something with a lightly-inclined near-geosynchronous circular orbit if the shadow winds up falling near the poles.